# Excel VBA: Copy Two Separate Ranges with Union

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy the header row and a specific row of a table with my loop. I then paste these two rows into Outlook, all using VBA. I'm trying to always copy Row 1, then copy Row 2 and use a union to combine them. Then, copy row 1 and row 3, then row 1 and row 4, etc. The problem is that Excel is copying the range of rows between as well. So it will copy Row 1 and Row 2, then Row 1, Row 2, and Row 3, etc.

```
Desired Result (each of these being a separate email):

Header Row
Row 2

Header Row
Row 3

Header Row
Row 4

Actual Result:

Header Row
Row 2

Header Row
Row 2
Row 3

Header Row
Row 2
Row 3
Row 4
```

I have tried doing two separate copy pastes to completely avoid the union, but this destroys the formatting.

Code

```
Sub email2()

Dim outlook As Object
Dim newEmail As Object
Dim xInspect As Object
Dim pageEditor As Object

Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2")
TableRows = tbl.ListRows.Count
MsgBox TableRows

For x = 1 To tbl.Range.Rows.Count

    Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set newEmail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

    With newEmail
        .To = Cells(x + 1, 36)
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Data"
        .Body = "Please find the requested information" & vbCrLf & "Best Regards"
        .Display

        Set xInspect = newEmail.GetInspector
        Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor

        'Table header'
        Set range1 = Sheet2.Range(Cells(1, 8), Cells(1, 36))
        Set range2 = Sheet2.Range(Cells(x + 1, 8), Cells(x + 1, 36))

        dblRange = Union(range1, range2).Copy

        'Sheet2.Range(Cells(x + 1, 8), Cells(x + 1, 36)).Copy'

        pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
        pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
        pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)

        .Display
        '.Send'
        Set pageEditor = Nothing
        Set xInspect = Nothing

    End With


Next x

End Sub
```

Thank you very much for any help,

Nash

Comment: `dblRange = Union(range1, range2).Copy` looks weird. Normally you just need to copy, then paste, not set a variable equal to the result of a copy. Also - you should specify what `Worksheet`, namely `Sheet2`, the `Cells` are on. Otherwise there's an implicit `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Hmm - if you select two non-contiguous rows in Excel, copy and then paste into an email, you get all the rows they encompass, not just those two...

Comment: @BigBen Yep, that's a good catch. Just tried it myself. So it seems like it's just a missing functionality from office? Can you think of any roundabouts to getting these rows into Outlook?

Comment: I tested this manually and it seemed to work: if you hide all the rows you don't want and select the entire range (both hidden rows and the 2 visible rows), only the visible cells are pasted in the email. Another option is to use a dummy sheet, copy each row onto the sheet, and then copy both rows from the sheet to the email.